# Searching for a letter in a word in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

I'm making a hangman game and I'm writing a function to search for a letter in the word. So when the user clicks on a letter, I am grabbing the text in there and searching for it in the chosen word.

The code I have written is:

```
    function searchLetter()
    {
     var aLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
     var aChosenWord = chosenWord.toLowerCase(); 
     //chosenWord is a global variable initialised in another function
     if(aChosenWord.indexOf(aLetter) != -1) 
     alert("Letter is there")
     else 
     {
         alert("Letter not found")
     }
    }
```

The variable 'letter' is a global variable and was given a value based on what has been clicked:

```
    $(function(){
  $('a').click(function () {
      letter = $(this).text();
    $(this).slideUp();
    searchLetter()
});
    });
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. I put in a bunch of alert boxes and my code seems to be grabbing the letters correctly.

When I run this however, every time I'm getting the value of -1 for indexOf; i.e. the letter is not found in the word.

I cannot figure out what it is I've done wrong here!!

Any input is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Variables `letter` and `chosenWord` are not defined in `searchLetter()` function.

Comment: @VisioN it's apparently global, according to the question. It would be helpful to see the HTML. The letter is taken from the text content of some `<a>` tag, which will be the same every time.

Comment: Have you thought about using Regex?

Comment: <a id = "A" value = "A"> A </a> &nbsp
<a id = "B" value = "B"> B </a> &nbsp

Comment: @Misemefein have you tried stepping through your code to see what values end up in aChosenWord and aLetter?

Comment: Sorry, added that comment before explaining - this is how my htnl looks

Comment: did you set chosenWord ?

Comment: @dhsto, Yes I ran it through a number of times and they are the correct values - i.e. if y is clicked, y is grabbed etc.

Comment: @dumass, yes I set chosenWord in another function and tested it to make sure if was grabbing a word - it's definitely working.

Comment: @Misemefein well, how are you calling that another function? on $('a').click?

Comment: @misemefein so you're saying that if aChosenWord="someword" and aLetter="w" that `"someword".indexOf("w")` returns `-1` every time? That's impressive.

Comment: Either `letter` or `chosenWord` are invalid strings. I don't see anything wrong with `searchLetter`. Please post a jsfiddle with your full code.

Comment: @dhsto, that's exactly what I'm saying!!! I have tested this extensively - let's say one of the words in my list is 'blabbering', and the letter I chose is 'b'; I checked this with alert boxes for 'chosenWord' and 'letter' and they have grabbed the word / letter correctly but indexOf is still returning -1. I'll click another letter, say 'n', and again I get -1. Sounds strange yes, but true!

Comment: $(this).text() returns the full text content of a html element, including spaces. In your previous comment, your links have spaces in them, so you're not searching for the letter "a" but for the string " a " with spaces.

Comment: Won't the 'YourLetter' variable return ' A ' (note the spaces!) since you are doing `$(this).text();`. Then when it goes to do an indexOf it would check against the string ' A ' and not 'A', or am I missing something here... You could try using `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).text();` to check

Comment: @Bart YES!!! Thank you so much, that's exactly what the problem was! I had another issue earlier and put the spaces in to make it easier to edit. All working now, thanks again :)

Comment: @Misemefein - to avoid potentially running into this issue in the future, you can switch `letter = $(this).text();` to `letter = $.trim($(this).text());` to remove any whitespaces from the beginning and end of the value.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a context for your global variables, e.g.:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var chosenWord;

    $('a').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.slideUp();
        searchLetter($this.text(), chosenWord);
    });

    // link that generates new game?
    $('.generate-new-word').function() {
        chosenWord = generateNewWord();
    });
});
```

The `searchLetter()` function receives the letter and word as its arguments and is thus decoupled from this code.

I've also written an example of how the word generation function can be integrated. As with `searchLetter()` this function has no knowledge of any global state.

This would be the implementation of your `searchLetter()`:

```
function searchLetter(letter, chosenWord)
{
   var aLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
   var aChosenWord = chosenWord.toLowerCase(); 

   if(aChosenWord.indexOf(aLetter) != -1) {
      alert("Letter is there")
   } else {
      alert("Letter not found")
   }
}
```

Organizing your code this way reduces the chance of introducing bugs in the code, because the context is managed exclusively inside only a small part of your code.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for that - I'm a newbie to jQuery so still getting my head around all this. Original problem solved (I had left in some spaces in my html file, doh!). But this is definitely helpful for tidying up my code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not an advocate for unnecessary global vars, the code below should do what you need.

**HTML**

```
<span id="chosenWord">Some awesome word</span>
<br />
<a href="#" class="letter">a</a>
<a href="#" class="letter">b</a>
<a href="#" class="letter">d</a>
<a href="#" class="letter">e</a>
```

**JS**

```
var letter,
    chosenWord = document.getElementById('chosenWord');
$('a').on('click', function () {
    if (chosenWord.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).text().toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        console.log('Found ' + $(this).text())
    } else {
        console.log($(this).text() + ' not found.');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2f3Ke/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you declare the global variable with? (check the scope):

```
var letter = ''
```

Why not prefer passing the variables within the argument list of the searching function?

Comment: Probably better to define global variables on `window` in case the scope is accidentally limited (it's best to avoid global variables as much as possible though).